# Two web applications with shared data

Tags: java, mysql, spring, web-applications

We are developing two web applications, webapp#1 is a store application, spring based app with mysql, the other (webapp#2) is a back office application for webapp#1.

We would like that backoffice operations (webapp#2) wont affect the DB of webapp#1 which is required to be with a very high availability.

The problem we are facing is how to share (if at all) entities that are relevant for both of the webapps.

For example, in order for the backoffice to generate On Demand reports on the store products it must aggregate on the entity "Product" and "Store".

Now , "Product" and "Store" are obviously entities that are in the webapp#1 schema, but in order for webapp#2 (backoffice) to generate the report it must have the same entites.

So, How exactly can we achieve this? should we duplicate "Product" and "Store" on both the webapps schemas? (and suffer from redundant data)  does redundancy is even a practice in real life? it seems too bad.

bear in mind that if the schemas are in the webapp#1 only , then the backoffice app can interfere when producing the report.

The report scenario is not the real issue, its just an example.

Best,

Comment: Is it only read-access that is interferent or is it read and write?

Comment: Read-access as well is interfering because some queries are mega complex

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to fire report generation queries on high availability database. You need to have some kind of staging DB to fire report generation queries on.

Comment: So i need data redundancy?

Comment: Not completely. But for e.g. if you are creating daily reports - Create a daily job which will import the live data into staging DB for that 1 day period. After the import is done, run your complex queries on the staging DB. 
After the reports are generated you can clear the data from staging DB. Make sure that staging DB holds the data for the period for which you are generating the report.

Comment: Daily reports are not my problem, but actual real time queries. so thats why i'm asking about redundancy, both webapps should create \ update the same data for the one webapp to not interfere with the other's

Comment: good question was wondering the same dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-database-synchronization.html checkout

Answer (score 0):

option 1:You could for example use web services. That reads data from a real aggregate table. which gets populated by some jobs.

optpion 2: Or have a reporting server with its own db that the webapp#2 reporting app can use. In this data base a replication at db level can be done at a predefined hour when the webapp#1 is not so loaded.